# Backup an Azure WebApp using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, backup, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I want to backup an Azure WebApp using PowerShell script. I know the *manual* way of backing up the web app through the Azure Portal. I am looking for an programmatic way (preferably PowerShell) to accomplish the same just like we can backup an Azure VM using PowerShell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the rest api which can be called from powershell. For a walk through: [websites-csm-backup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-csm-backup/)